# Infura shows only file names instead of picture

Tags: python, ipfs

Could you help mw to figure out why Infura IPFS shows only file names. I'd like to see the picture.

This is how I generate a picture:

```
from randimage import get_random_image, show_array
import matplotlib
import random

def generateImage():
    img_size = (256,256)
    img = get_random_image(img_size)  #returns numpy array
    #show_array(img) #shows the image
    image_name = str(random.randrange(100000000000000))
    image_name = image_name + ".png"
    matplotlib.image.imsave(image_name, img)

    return image_name
```

This is how I upload picture:

```
    file = generateImage()

    projectId = "your number"
    projectSecret = "your number"
    endpoint = "https://ipfs.infura.io:5001"

    ### CREATE AN ARRAY OF TEST FILES ###
    files = {
        'file': file
    }

    ### ADD FILE TO IPFS AND SAVE THE HASH ###
    response1 = requests.post(endpoint + '/api/v0/add', files=files, auth=(projectId, projectSecret))
    print(response1)
    hash = response1.text.split(",")[1].split(":")[1].replace('"','')
```

This is how I try to see the picture:

https://infura-ipfs.io/ipfs/QmP3gZWWSzhTY7BzsPuMvT5VTxpRqAZrK5ub8XS5U5YfvM

Answer (score 0):

I found the wrong thing in my code. Should be:

```
with open(file, "rb") as a_file:
            file_dict = {"file_to_upload.txt": a_file}
            response1 = requests.post(endpoint + '/api/v0/add', files=file_dict, auth=(projectId, projectSecret))
            print(response1)
            hash = response1.text.split(",")[1].split(":")[1].replace('"','')
            print(hash)
```